# What importance of battery " voltage" between cathode and anode in photocell?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, photons, photoelectric-effect

In photocell at threshold frequency $f=f_0$ and voltage $>0$ (between cathode - and anode +)

1. Is current $=0$ at $f=f_0$ and $v>0$?
2. When voltage $>0$ and $f=f_0$, Does photoelectron have KE to go to anode?

[image]

Comment: Concerning part 1: Possible duplicate of [Is photocell current equal zero at threshold frequency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485892/is-photocell-current-equal-zero-at-threshold-frequency)